# How to add or customize response from laravel validation

Tags: laravel

I've searched over the internet to find answer for my issue but could not find it. Please see details below.

**What response I currently have**

```
{
    "message": "The expected salary field is required.",
    "errors": {
        "expected_salary": [
            "The expected salary field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

**What I need:**

```
{
    "status": "FAILED",
    "message": "The expected salary field is required.",
    "errors": {
        "expected_salary": [
            "The expected salary field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

**Validation Rules:**

```
public function rules()
{
    return ['expected_salary' => 'required];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By overriding the `failedValidation` method, you can flexibly customize the validation error response for a specific `FormRequest`.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class FooBarRequest extends FormRequest
{
    // your other code ...

    /**
     * Handle a failed validation attempt.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator  $validator
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        throw (new HttpResponseException(response([
            'status' => 'FAILED',
            'message' => $validator->errors()->first(),
            'errors' => $validator->errors()->toArray(),
        ]), Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY));
    }
}
```

Further reading: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-make-a-custom-formrequest-error-response-in-laravel-55

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
  $error = $validator->errors();
   return response()->json([
            'staatus' => "Failed",
            'error' => $error,
            'success' => false,
            'message'=>'',
        ]); 
}
```

Comment: This would not work on my case since im using the validation feature of laravel

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your invalid response data globally in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`.

It overrides from `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php`.

Below is my examples...

```
protected function invalidJson($request, ValidationException $exception)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'code' => $exception->status,
            'message' => collect($exception->errors())->first(),
            'data' => [
                'errors' => $exception->errors(),
                'exception' => in_array(config('app.env'), ['local', 'dev']) ? $this->convertExceptionToArray($exception) : [],
                'request' => $request->all()
            ]
        ], $exception->status);
    }
```

Comment: this is for global scope. what if I just need it for a specific request validation not globally? is it possible as well?

Comment: Use `try-catch`. `$request->validate()` throws `ValidationException` when request is invalid.