How to disable default ValidationException handler?
I have a store method in DocumentController. This method use custom laravel FormRequest to validate request data. A try catch block in this store method should handle the ValidationException by sending custom JSON message along with the errors.
DocumentController.php
public function store(DocumentStoreRequest $req) // controller
    {
        try
        {
            $validData = $req->validated();

            $path = $this->storeImage($req->file('document_file'));
            $validData['doc_path'] = $path;
            unset($validData['document_file']);

            Document::create($validData);
            return response()->json([
                "message"=>"Add document for citizen $validData[nik] is success",
                "data"=>$validData
            ], 201);
        }
        catch(ValidationException $e) // Should handle the ValidationException
        {
            return response()->json([
                "message"=>"Validation error",
                "errors"=>$e->errors()
            ], 422);
        }
        catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => "Interval Server Error : \n".$e->getMessage(),
                'file' => $e->getFile(),
                'line' => $e->getLine(),
                'trace' => $e->getTrace(),
            ], 500);
        }
    }

private function storeImage($file)
    {
        $file_name = time() . '-' . uniqid() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = "public/images";
        $file_path = $file->storeAs($path, $file_name);
        return $file_path;
    }

DocumentStoreRequest.php
public function rules(): array // FormRequest
    {
        return [
            "citizen_id"=>["required", "exists:citizens,id"],
            "document_file"=>["required", "image:png"],
            "type_id"=>["required", new OnlyOneTypeOfDocument($this->citizen_id)]
        ];
    }

OnlyOneTypeOfDocument.php
private $citizen;
public function __construct($citizen_id)
    {
        $this->citizen = Citizen::find($citizen_id);
    }
public function validate(string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail): void // custom validation rule
    {
        if($this->citizen==null) return;
        $document=$this->citizen->documents->where("id", "!=", $value);
        if($document->count() > 0) // fail the validation if citizen already have a document with the same type
        {
            $type_name = $document->first()->documentType->name;
            $nik = $this->citizen->nik;

            $fail("The document with type of ".$type_name." already exists for citizen ".$nik);
        }

    }

The problem is, it seems that laravel built in handler class is interfering with the process and catch the ValidationException before it can be handled by the try catch block in the store method.
I want to disable this 'default ValidationException handling'. I have tried to alter the handler.php file and the app.php in bootstrap folder, but none of those give me the correct solutions for my problem.
Default Response
{
    "message": "The document file field is required. (and 1 more error)",
    "errors": {
        "document_file": [
            "The document file field is required."
        ],
        "type_id": [
            "The document with type of Kartu Keluarga already exists for citizen 3201010101010002"
        ]
    }
}

Desired Response
{
    "message": "Validation Error",
    "errors": {
        "document_file": [
            "The document file field is required."
        ],
        "type_id": [
            "The document with type of Kartu Keluarga already exists for citizen 3201010101010002"
        ]
    }
}


The validation and return is being handled by the DocumentStoreRequest, before it gets to the controller, so it doesn't even get to that try/catch. I'd suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73075372/how-to-add-or-customize-response-from-laravel-validation to change how your response is being sent back.
